# Bootstrap 4 Img + Span Alignment

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do two things:
1 - Align a Span to the middle of an Img;
2 - Align the Span to the right of the parent div

This is what I have today -> [image]

This is the current code:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: right;">
  <img src="thumbnails/americares.png" class="pl-2 pb-2">
  <span class="price" style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:5px;">$20</span>
</div>
```

Class price looks like this:

```
<style>
.price{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: #29303b;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

I need to move the price here -> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add display flex to the parent container.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And you probably won't need `padding-bottom: 15px;` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex row. Since you are using bootstrap 4, we can implement this.

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <img src="thumbnails/americares.png">
  <span class="price">$20</span>
</div>
```